# Specifying priors over softmax outputs

Tags: neural-networks, prior, softmax, weight-initialization

Looking to train a simple single-layered NN with a N-dim softmax output (and a relatively small feature vector size, ~2-10) in a streaming fashion accumulating K samples in a buffer and then performing batch gradient descent steps to update the weights. The samples have soft labels as outputs instead of one-hot encoding generated by an alternate algorithm.

I would like to prevent overconfident softmax predictions due to random weight initializations when the number of training steps are low. One way I can think of doing this is basically to have an uninformative prior over the softmax outputs in the face of a lack of data (I do not yet know what might constitute a "lack" of data but it could be as simple as a threshold on the dataset size). 

How might I go about enforcing such an uninformative prior on the softmax output? The naive way I thought of approaching this was to generate a bunch of samples with an uninformative prior for all of them and then "pre-train" the NN to get it to that stage. But I imagine there is a more principled approach of getting this to work. Label smoothing is also something I've found but I'm not sure it would fit well with a dataset with soft labels. Any suggestions/techniques to look into would be appreciated.